# Print dynamic range to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to print an active range to a pdf. I get a runtime error.

The end result I am looking for:

- Set the active range (A1:F1 & Down to the last line of active data).
- Set to export with all columns fit to a single page.
- Save the PDF with "a2" which is the name of the report.

```vb
Sub Create_PDF()
' Create and save .pdf
Dim pdfName As String

pdfName = Range("A2").Text
FullName = "P:\DEN-Dept\Partner_Support\Public\Generated Letters\Fee Summary Spreadsheets\" & pdfName & " - " & Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy hh mm") & ".pdf"
'Sets the name and location for the new file

Dim myrange As String

myrange = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Address
'sets the string end for the print area

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = "$A$1:" & myrange
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
'Setting the spreadsheet to print active content with columns fit to single page

If Dir(FullName) <> vbNullString Then

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="P:\DEN-Dept\Partner_Support\Public\Generated Letters\Fee Summary Spreadsheets\" & pdfName & " - " & Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy hh mm") & ".pdf" _
      , Quality:=xlQualityMedium, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Else

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="P:\DEN-Dept\Partner_Support\Public\Generated Letters\Fee Summary Spreadsheets\" & pdfName & Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy hh mm") & ".pdf" _
      , Quality:=xlQualityMedium, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End If
'This is where I am getting the runtime error and the file is not saving

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works well for me without any errors. This means the problem is with your data. Check the value you have in Range("A2"), keeping in mind the file naming rules in Windows system (certain characters are not allowed).  Also check that you have some values in column F. Another possibility is that your folder path string has some typos or it's not accessible.

Comment: I found the issue: FullName = "P:\DEN-Dept\Partner_Support\Public\Generated Letters\Fee Summary Spreadsheets\" & pdfName & " - " & Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy hh mm") & ".pdf"

It didn't like me adding the date to the name of the file. 

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the path and/or file name because the problem is there.

Check that you are not entering strange characters and that the path is accessible and that Excel can save files in it.

I just tested your code on my computer in an accessible path and it works perfectly. However, if I try to save the file to a protected path (for example "C:/") I get your same error.

All the best.

Comment: The problem was in my definition of FullName. I took that out and it works. 

I do have a follow up here. At the bottom of my sheet I have 4 merged cells that include disclaimers that are required. The problem here is that with the current code, it wont recognize those bottom 4 cells since they fall under column 1 not column 6. Is there a way to figure in that offset as well?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is to add to the range of cells also the one that contains the text. Something like:

`With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            .PrintArea = "$A$1:" & myrange & ":$A$32" 'A32 or whatever cell your text is in
               .Orientation = xlPortrait
               .Zoom = False
                       .FitToPagesTall = False
                       .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With`

Comment: Well this is the challenge, the number of rows is dynamic based on the data imported. Thats why I need to find the bottom of the active data. In a perfect world that would look like A1:F100 but F technically only goes to 96 because those bottom 4 cells are merged. I need a way for it to identify the bottom and then add four more rows. Does that help?

Comment: There are many methods for get the last user row in Excel. For example: 
`Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`
or
`Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`
or
`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row`

And then you can add al new rows you need with:

`Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert`